# Eclipse Juno Cannot Create Server After Update

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, eclipse-juno

I just updated my eclipse juno and after an update, This shows up!

[image]

The errors are

```
Could not create the view: org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.ServersView
```

And all of my project files were corrupted.how would I resolve this? is there anyway I can return the previous state or version of my Eclipse?

Comment: I would suggest you to install a fresh version of Juno and simply point the workspace to the old one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse JUNO has some bugs, I strongly recommend you to go back to Indigo, I had a lot of issues when updating to Juno and installing Juno, that's why I preferred to get back to my Eclipse Indigo. I could notice that there's also an impact in memory, previous versions of Eclipse consume less resources and are faster. If you have a good computer and with a good processor, I think there's no problem, but you can still always save memory for other needs. If you still want the latest release, download JUNO directly from the page, as I mentioned before, it has some new features as well as some bugs. Best regards